# Where do I get the iOS toolbar icons for up/down arrow?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, imageicon

I'm looking for these button icons, [image: icons]
, that I found in the [Apple developer's guide for working with toolbars (almost half way down the page](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/overview/themes/), but I can't find them in the storyboard.

I found a bunch of other icons in the storyboard for images, as shown here on the right, and I expected they would be there but they weren't.
[image: storyboard images]

Where do I get all these icons that Apple suggests I use? I would really like to use the up/down arrows for casting votes in my app.

Specifically, where can I get all of the images found in [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/overview/themes/) [image: Apple images]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Art/icon_family_2x.png))</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately these are all custom icons that are not available out of the box. You can google "UIToolBar icons" to see if someone is kind enough to provide them for free download. Otherwise you may have to pay for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not available. They're just a list of icons they have developed for iOS as a showcase. You should look into making them yourself and applying them as a UIButtonTypeCustom. Small drawback is that if the iOS style changes (like iOS6 -> iOS7) you need to manually update your custom buttons while the rest is automatically upgraded.

Comment: Man, those guys suck.

Comment: I have used stock sites like istockphoto to get icon sets and other artwork